# Get layers and features having the coordinates defined

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-5

I have defined coordinates. I need to know if there is any way to know the layers or features that exist in those coordinates. Is that possible?

I have used the following function, but this does it with respect to the map pixels and I want with respect to some coordinates

```
var result = ol_interaction_Snap.prototype.snapTo.call(this, pixel, pixelCoordinate, map);

    if (result.snapped) {
        var p = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(pixel);
        var feature = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(p);
        this.dispatchEvent(new mgis_ObjectEvent("aftersnap", feature));
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: Did you try the function above along with https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#getPixelFromCoordinate ?

Comment: Yes, it still doesn't work. I enclose the code of what I want to do. I have specific coordinates and I want to know if there are features in those coordinates.

I modify the code of the main publication in case you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [getFeaturesAtCoordinate](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#getFeaturesAtCoordinate) or [getFeaturesInExtent](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#getFeaturesInExtent) for the sources of your map.
Just create a small extent around your coords.

```
var extent = ol.extent.boundingExtent([ coordinate ]);
extent = ol.extent.buffer(extent, .1); 
// test if features 
if (source.getFeaturesInExtent(extent).length) { 
... 
}
```